# Combine two plots created with effects package in R

Tags: r, graphics, effects

I have the following Problem. After running an ordered logit model, I want to R's effects package to visualize the results. This works fine and I did so for two independent variables,  then I tried to combine the two plots. However, this does not seem to work. I provide a little replicable example here so you can see my problem for yourself:

```
library(car)
data(Chile)
mod <- polr(vote ~ age + log(income), data=Chile)

eff <- effect("log(income)", mod)
plot1 <- plot(eff, style="stacked",rug=F, key.args=list(space="right"))

eff2 <- effect("age", mod)
plot2 <- plot(eff2, style="stacked",rug=F, key.args=list(space="right"))
```

I can print these two plots now independently, but when I try to plot them together, the first plot is overwritten. I tried setting `par(mfrow=c(2,1))`, which didn't work. Next I tried the following:

```
print(plot1, position=c(0, .5, 1, 1), more=T)
print(plot2, position=c(0,0, 1, .5))
```

In this latter case, the positions of the two plots are just fine, but still the first plot vanishes once I add the second (or better, it is overwritten). Any suggestions how to prevent this behavior would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading down the long list of arguments to `?print.eff` we see that there are some arguments for doing just this:

```
plot(eff, style="stacked",rug=F, key.args=list(space="right"),
     row = 1,col = 1,nrow = 1,ncol = 2,more = TRUE)
plot(eff2, style="stacked",rug=F, key.args=list(space="right"),
     row = 1,col = 2,nrow = 1,ncol = 2)
```

The reason `par()` didn't work is because this package is using **lattice** graphics, which are based on the **grid** system, which is incompatible with base graphics. Neither `par()` nor `layout` will have any effect on grid graphics.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
plot(eff,col=1,row=2,ncol=1,nrow=2,style="stacked",rug=F,
  key.args=list(space="right"),more=T)
plot(eff2,col=1,row=1,ncol=1,nrow=2,style="stacked",rug=F, 
  key.args=list(space="right"))
```

edit: Too late...